# C# .Date syntax

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to working on `Date` instead of `DateTime` in C#, which it will only return me **Date: 01/01/2001** instead of **DateTime: 01/01/2001 12:00:00 AM**.  I had browse through [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and I hit this `.Date` example

so here I try:

```
while (obj.Read())
   {
      var pdate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj["PurchaseDate"]);
      var edate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj["ExpiredDate"]);
      class.Add(new myClass()
           {
               PurchaseDate = pdate.Date.ToString(),
               ExpiredDate = edate.Date.ToString(),
           }
   );
}
```

I am trying to get data using query, and here I return a `<List>` and I tried to use `.Date`,
However, I still get the format of **DateTime: 01/01/2001 12:00:00 AM**

May I know that is it my syntax error or is there had a better way to perform such action?

**My `PurchaseDate` and `ExpiredDate` is a `string`

---

### Update

Thanks for answers from **Kirin** and **Kevin**

My code worked and change to follows:

```
var pdate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj["PurchaseDate"]);
var edate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj["ExpiredDate"]);
class.Add(new myClass()
{
   PurchaseDate = pdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
   ExpiredDate = edate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
}
```

Comment: From [`DateTime.Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1) specs:  _the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)._

Comment: Sidenote: If `obj` is some database query result or even user input, do not trust it to be "convertible". I'd recommend `DateTime.TryParse` or `TryParseExact`.

Comment: Hi @Fildor so it would be `DateTime.TryParse(obj["PurchaseDate"]);` ?

Comment: Please refer to its Docs: [DateTime.TryParse(string, DateTime)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_DateTime__)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.Date` still return an object of `DateTime` type which includes the time part. Try `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

Comment: Hi Kirin, is it a necessary that month `mm` need to be capitalize? as `MM`

Comment: @Lawraoke "mm" is "minutes". "MM" is "Month".

Comment: `ToString("d")` will be simpler and more readable and allows to reflect the current culture

Comment: @Lawraoke Yes, the `mm` means minute, not month. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 2):

That's just how DateTime.Date works according to the documentation. `DateTime.Date` returns:

> A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00).

If you want just the day month and year you need to format it

```
var pdate = Convert.ToDateTime(obj["PurchaseDate"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1